# Plutus-tx on XEON v2

Tags: plutustx, ghc

I am trying to compile plutus script on 'Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2' machine.  I initialized nix flake from `input-output-hk/iogx` haskell template (tried with ghc96 and ghc92), entered development environment with `nix develop` and tried to compile simple code like

```
integerOne :: CompiledCode Integer
integerOne = $$(compile [|| (1 :: Integer) ||])
```

Compilation fails with

```
Error: cabal: Failed to build hello-1.0.0.2. The build process terminated with exit code -4
```

And when I try to load the code to ghci, it reports

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

On my laptop it compiles successfully.

Looking at the coredump I discovered that the instruction was `mulx` from `adx` cpu feature.  `/proc/cpuinfo` says that my laptop has that feature, but the server does not.

Except for compiling with `PlutusTx.compile` anything other from ghc seems to work on the server well.

**The question is**, is there any way to run this on my server?  Any flag or fix to `plutus-tx` or ghc?  Can anyone point me to the part of `plutus-tx` package (or the proper `ghc`?) that generates that instruction?

Comment: I created the ticket: https://github.com/IntersectMBO/plutus/issues/5842

Answer (score 0):

try this [flake.nix](https://github.com/schwarzer-swan/ppbl1013/blob/main/flake.nix), it uses the iogx as well with plutus-tx >= 1.21.  The corresponding code builds on my lenovo p1 laptop with Xeon CPU. Although, I am not sure if it is the exact CPU as your specs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried your flake.  I cloned the repo and tried to enter development environment.  When nix built it, it dumped core while compiling `plutus-script-utils` so I believe the repo also has the same problem.